# Replace one character with two using replace function

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am trying to convert accented characters to regular characters. Some characters need to be replaced with two characters. I tried `MID(string,i,2)`.

```
Function ChangeAccent(thestring As String)
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim C As String * 1
Dim D As String * 1
Dim i As Integer

Const LatChars="ßÄÖÜäöü"
Const OrgChars= "SSAEOEUEaeoeue"
For i = 1 To Len(LatChars)
    A = Mid(LatChars, i, 1)
    B = Mid(OrgChars, i, 2)
    thestring = Replace(thestring, A, B)
Next

Const AccChars="ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const RegChars= "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
    C = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
    D = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
    thestring = Replace(thestring, C, D)
Next

ChangeAccent = thestring
End Function
```

The code is working for one by one replacement (1 character by 1 character).

I want to replace one character in the variable LatChars with 2 characters in OrgChars. i.e ß with SS, Ä with AE and so on.

The `Mid(OrgChars, i,2)` is not extracting two characters.

Comment: `Mid(OrgChars,i,2)` is, in fact, extracting 2 chars, but you have declared `B` to be a string of length 1.  Also, your `i` is not indexing properly for `OrgChars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor changes:

> Dim B As String * 2
>
> B = Mid(OrgChars, i * 2 - 1, 2)

```
Option Explicit
Function ChangeAccent(thestring As String)
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 2
Dim C As String * 1
Dim D As String * 1
Dim i As Integer

Const LatChars = "ßÄÖÜäöü"
Const OrgChars = "SSAEOEUEaeoeue"
For i = 1 To Len(LatChars)
    A = Mid(LatChars, i, 1)
    B = Mid(OrgChars, i * 2 - 1, 2)
    thestring = Replace(thestring, A, B)
Next

Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
C = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
D = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
thestring = Replace(thestring, C, D)
Next

ChangeAccent = thestring
End Function
```

Comment: I knew I was missing on something..i knew it would be a silly error somewhere. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: @alex_gabriel Glad to help.  If my response solved your problem, could you please mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use two [arrays](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html).  One that contains the character you wish to replace and the other its replacement.  This method depends on both arrays being in sync with one another.  Element 1 in the first array must match element 1 in the second, and so on.

This method allows you to ignore the string lengths.  There is no longer any need to process 1 and 2 character replacement strings separately.  This code can also scale to 3, 4 or more character replacements without a logic change.

I've used the [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function to build the arrays.  I find this saves time when typing out the code.  But you may prefer to define the elements individually, which is arguably easier to read.

**Example**

```
Sub Demo001()
' Demos how to replace special charaters of various lenghts.

    Dim ReplaceThis() As String     ' Array of characters to replace.
    Dim WithThis() As String        ' Array of replacement characters.
    Dim c As Integer                ' Counter to loop over array.
    Dim Sample As String            ' Contains demo string.

        ' Set up demo string.
        Sample = "ß - Ä - Š"

        ' Create arrays using split function and comma delimitor.
        ReplaceThis = Split("ß,Ä,Š", ",")
        WithThis = Split("SS,AE,S", ",")

        ' Loop over replacements.
        For c = LBound(ReplaceThis) To UBound(ReplaceThis)
            Sample = Replace(Sample, ReplaceThis(c), WithThis(c))
        Next

        ' Show result.
        MsgBox Sample
End Sub
```

**Returns**

```
SS - AE - S
```

**EDIT:  Answer rewritten as first attempt misunderstood - and did not answer - op question**

Comment: That's what I used in the code too..Please take a look at my code above and let me know how I should manipulate it.

Comment: I think one approach is to use arrays.  I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

```
B = Mid(OrgChars, i,2)
```

Should probably be

```
B = Mid(OrgChars, i*2-1,2)
```